# How to do error handling in web application written in Perl (CGI.pm)?

Tags: perl, web-applications, cgi

When writing / maintaining web application written in Perl using CGI.pm, how should I handle errors (exceptions)?  Webapp in question can be deployed as plain CGI app, as FastCGI app (using CGI::Fast), and as mod_perl app using ModPerl::Registry handler.

I mean here handling errors like page not found, or configuration forbids given action, or some external command used in the app failed (like e.g. cannot connect to the database).

---

**Edit:** *added 2010-12-14*.

The example code flow could look like this:

```
sub run {

    ...
    run_request();
    ...

}

sub run_request {

    ...
    $actions{$cgi->param('a')}->();
    ...

}

sub action_foo {

    foo_body()

}

sub foo_body {

    check_something()
        or handle_error(some description);

}
```

I mean here that error might have be to be thrown / handled in some nested call, and not only in the action handler / route handler.

Comment: I've always liked how CGI::Prototype handles this sort of thing. At any point in flow control, you can effectively switch routes. This is a tough question to answer in general because it's a design and architecture question, and different frameworks have different thoughts about how things should happen. Maybe you can make a more narrow question?

Comment: @casperOne - When you (as moderator) delete other answer(s), please be so nice and add a comment to that answer with EXACT reason. Right now it looks like you are just one of #Briandfoy's followers, as he inspects every my step (which I don't mind).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the appropriate status code to the header method as per [Creating A Standard HTTP Header](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI#CREATING_A_STANDARD_HTTP_HEADER)

Comment: I know how to correctly generate error page.  What I am about is **code flow**.